# Automatically quit Vim if NERDTree and TagList are the last and only buffers

Tags: vim, nerdtree, taglist

Basically, my `.vimrc` starts [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net) and NERDTree when Vim is launched, as splits on the left and on the right of the normal file buffer.

I want to close Vim when, closing the last buffer/tab, TagList and NERDTree splits are the only remained. I'm already using [vim-nerdtree-tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) and it works great when NERDTree is the only and last buffer open.

I'm aware that such topic has been discussed here on StackOverflow but I cannot find anything related to both NERDTree and TagList.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow = 1
will close Tag_list window if it's the last window, look at http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/manual.html for more infomation about Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow, I'm not sure if you are looking for this, if not, please delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like... (untested)

```
fun! NoExcitingBuffersLeft()
   if tabpagenr("$") == 1 && winnr("$") == 2
      let window1 = bufname(winbufnr(1))
      let window2 = bufname(winbufnr(2))
      if (window1 == t:NERDTreeBufName || window1 == "__Tag_List__") &&
         (window2 == t:NERDTreeBufName || window2 == "__Tag_List__")
         quit
      endif
   endif
endfun
```

then tie that function to an autocommand...

```
au WinEnter * call NoExcitingBuffersLeft()<cr>
```

I don't use either of those plugins, so you may need to adjust the `t:NERDTreeBufName` and `__Tag_List__`.

Comment: A few months later, this was useful to me :-) (btw, the `__Tag_List__` is correct, didn't check the NERDTree)

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Conner's idea, I've made a functional solution here.

```
" If only 2 windows left, NERDTree and Tag_List, close vim or current tab
fun! NoExcitingBuffersLeft()
  if winnr("$") == 3
    let w1 = bufname(winbufnr(1))
    let w2 = bufname(winbufnr(2))
    let w3 = bufname(winbufnr(3))
    if (exists(":NERDTree")) && (w1 == "__Tag_List__" || w2 == "__Tag_List__" || w3 == "__Tag_List__")
      if tabpagenr("$") == 1
        exec 'qa'
      else
        exec 'tabclose'
      endif
    endif
  endif
endfun
autocmd BufWinLeave * call NoExcitingBuffersLeft()
```

Need vim 7.0+ for the BufWinLeave event.
Closes the tab if more than one tab is open, otherwise quits vim.
This way, the auto-command is tied to when you close the last window that's not NERDTree or Tag_List, rather than upon entering one of the two windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice extendable solution. To validate against other plugins/window types just add them to the regex check.

```
function! s:CloseAddons()
    for w in range(1, winnr('$'))
        if bufname(winbufnr(w)) !~# '__Tagbar\|NERD_tree_\|coc-explorer'
                \ && getbufvar(winbufnr(w), "&buftype") !=? "quickfix"
            return
        endif
    endfor

    if tabpagenr('$') ==? 1
        execute 'quitall'
    else
        execute 'tabclose'
    endif
endfunction
```