# Automatically Quit Vim if NERDTree and TagList are the only 2 Buffers Left

Tags: linux, vim, nerdtree, taglist

I have this code taken from another StackOverflow user Conner, from this question [Automatically quit Vim if NERDTree and TagList are the last and only buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672657/automatically-quit-vim-if-nerdtree-and-taglist-are-the-last-and-only-buffers)

(There wasn't an option for me to comment on that question, so my only option was to ask a new one).

The question is: How do I close Vim editor (in Linux Mint) if only NERDTree and TagList are the only two buffers left?

The answer provided was:

```
" If only 2 windows left, NERDTree and Tag_List, close vim or current tab
fun! NoExcitingBuffersLeft()
  if winnr("$") == 3
    let w1 = bufname(winbufnr(1))
    let w2 = bufname(winbufnr(2))
    let w3 = bufname(winbufnr(3))
    if (exists(":NERDTree")) && (w1 == "__Tag_List__" || w2 == "__Tag_List__" || w3 == "__Tag_List__")
      if tabpagenr("$") == 1
        exec 'qa'
      else
        exec 'tabclose'
      endif
    endif
  endif
endfun
autocmd BufWinLeave * call NoExcitingBuffersLeft()
```

But that does not work properly. Is closes whenever I close the last "exciting" buffer (one that is non-NERDTree or non-TagList), but it also closes whenever I try to open a new file from NERDTree (by double clicking on a filename in the "explorer").

Honestly, I do not understand this code too well. I have tried to mess around with it but I couldn't get the results I would like.

How do I alter this code to not close when I open a new file from NERDTree explorer?

Thank you, Conner, and the rest of the community!

Answer (score 0):

From the Taglist manual, put on your .vimrc file

```
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow=1
```

I don't use NERDTree, but you may succeed with the following

```
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif
```